# QML sorting in tableview is very slowly

Tags: sorting, qml, tableview, qtquickcontrols

I use QML TableView + own QAbstractTableModel and QSortFilterProxyModel. I've implemented sorting, but it works slowly. I've used these models without QML, but with QTableView - it worked perfectly. 30 000 items sort less then 1 secs.
Can anybody help? Where problem is?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Creator has a QML profiler. Do you have any custom styling for the TableView?

Comment: How to use QML profiler? Because I've used WPF and Very Sleepy

Comment: And I've profiled it. Profiler showed me the problem in

    void MySortFilterProxyModel::Sort(const QByteArray& role, Qt::SortOrder order){
QSortFilterProxyModel::setSortRole(RoleKey(role));
    sort(0, order);
    invalidate();
}

Comment: These code is called from QML
onSortIndicatorColumnChanged: MySortFilterProxyModel.Sort(table.getColumn(table.sortIndicatorColumn).ro‌​le, sortIndicatorOrder)
onSortIndicatorOrderChanged: MySortFilterProxyModel.Sort(table.getColumn(table.sortIndicatorColumn).ro‌​le, sortIndicatorOrder)
Component.onCompleted:{ MySortFilterProxyModel.Sort(table.getColumn(sortIndicatorColumn).role, sortIndicatorOrder)}

Comment: I've used WPF and Very Sleepy, how can I use QML Profiler?

Comment: There's documentation for it: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html

Comment: Also, We have used style for TableView like http://joxi.ru/ZrJXZ3zs15K7n2

Comment: @Mitch
I've used QML profiler and it has showed me http://joxi.ru/V2VB8qbu0Xydo2. Maybe problem in painting data in QML ? Because if i use QT Delegate + QT Model, I don't have problem with sorting.

Comment: How many rows are visible at a time? And how many columns are there per row?

Comment: 13 rows are visible at a time and table has 12 columns per row and 6 columns are visible at a time.
I've tested with one column but performance is bad. The table has 10 000 rows and more.

Comment: What if you try just using a ListView instead of TableView? It could be that the styling in TableView is slowing it down.

Comment: I've just checked sorting by model without updating GUI, I've used 54 000 items - sort works perfectly. Now I'm going to try disabled table style and check ListView

Comment: I've disabled TableStyles, remove 10 column (2 is stayed) but sorting works slowly. Maybe TableView tried to paint WHOLE 54 000 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've supposed that QML repaint all items while Model is sorting data (in every iteration). I've found solution, for sorting you have to:

1. Turn off model in QML
2. Sorting items (use model)
3. Return back model.

For example

```
onSortIndicatorOrderChanged: {
    model = null
    MyModel.Sort(...)
    model = MyModel
}
```

More details https://forum.qt.io/topic/52026/solved-sorting-qml-tableview-is-slow/4

Comment: Good to see you found a workaround. It would be great if you could file a bug report with a reproducible example. Seems like a pretty nasty issue.

Comment: Do you mean, create bug in QT jira?

Comment: Yep: bugreports.qt.io